# sed: mix explicit and regex phrases

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I'm trying to write a sed command to remove a specific string followed by two digits. So far I have:

```
sed -e 's/bizzbuzz\([0-9][0-9]\)//' file.txt
```

but I cant seem to get the syntax right. Any suggestions?

Comment: Although the parentheses is unnecessary, your current regex pattern would work fine. Can you give an example of what output you *are* getting and what output you *want* to get?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
sed -re 's/bizzbuzz[0-9]{2}//' file.txt
```

and

```
sed -re 's/\bbizzbuzz[0-9]{2}\b//' file.txt
```

if the searched string have [*word boundary*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html)

```
sed -e 's/bizzbuzz[0-9]\{2\}//' file.txt
```

if you don't have `GNU sed`

Comment: Note that the `-r` option only works in GNU sed and in recent versions of FreeBSD.  In older FreeBSD or in OSX, you should use the `-E` option instead (the same option used to get extended regexes in grep).  Also, the `\b` short-cut does not seem to be portable.  Always best to qualify platform-specific answers, especially when the question doesn't include platform-specific tags.

Comment: Thanks, true, added non GNU solution.

Answer (score 1):

Your current approach seems like it should work fine:

```
$ echo 'FOO bizzbuzz56 BAR' | sed -e 's/bizzbuzz\([0-9][0-9]\)//'
FOO  BAR
```

Comment: AFAIK, no spaces in OP question between letters and digits F.J

Comment: @sputnick Not sure what you mean, where does it look like I'm adding spaces?

Comment: ...or maybe that's you, we just makes assumptions on OP needs ;) We are close to psychics sometimes =)

Answer (score 0):

As said in other answer, the syntax seems to be fine (with unnecesary parenthesis).
But may be you want to replace *all* the strings found in each line ? In that case, you should add a 'g' at the end of the 's' command:

`sed -e 's/bizzbuzz\([0-9][0-9]\)//g' file.txt`